# DoubleTap Gesture not working on my view (strange behavior) but in simulator working fine

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

If i'm setting negative offset, double tap not working. my code as follows:
(if >=0 then double tap working)

```
    self.doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doDoubleTap:)];
    self.doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.doubleTap];

//Some where
    scrollView.contentOffset=CGPointMake(-(self.scrView.frame.size.width-self.objDrawingView.frame.size.width)/2.0, -(self.scrView.frame.size.height-self.objDrawingView.frame.size.height)/2.0);
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Then add the tapGesture into the scrollView itself.

Comment: Have you added scrollview on entire view ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tapgesture into superview to get hierarchy gesture, like here is scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

try to add following line in your view did load before setting content offset

```
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```